# Code Runs, just not to exactly how I need it to

Tags: ruby

This is the code graciously helped out by another community member.

```
require 'date'

today = Date.today


hires = [
  { name: 'Jerry', date: Date.new(2021, 8, 15) },
  { name: 'Berry', date: Date.new(2021, 8, 13) },
  { name: 'Jack', date: Date.new(2021, 8, 19) }
]


def report(hires, today)
  hires.each do |hire|
    puts(
      format(
        '%s , needs vacation',
        hire[:name],
        hire[:date],
        today - hire[:date]
      )
    )
  end
end
report(hires,today)
```

This code will output

```
Jerry was hired on 2021-05-13, which is X days ago
Berry was hired on 2021-05-06, which is X days ago # The X's are examples :)
Jack was hired on 2021-05-17, which is X days ago
```

Basically what I would like it to do is run the code, and it only show me people who have been hired 91-97 days ago from todays date, and output their name. So they output would preferably post something like.

```
Jerry, needs vacation
Berry, needs vacation
# it would only say Jerry and Berry Because Jack had not rolled over yet.
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: May I suggest reading about "Conditional Execution" in the "Expressions" chapter of [Programming Ruby](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)

Comment: If you want your code to do something you need to write the code which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* narrow your problem down to a concise, focused, simple, short [mre] and ask a specific, focused, narrow question on [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'select' enumerator for arrays

> https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

```ruby
require 'date'

VACATION_INTERVAL = (91..97).freeze

hires = [
  { name: 'Jerry', date: Date.new(2021, 8, 15) },
  { name: 'Berry', date: Date.new(2021, 8, 13) },
  { name: 'Jack', date: Date.new(2021, 8, 19) }
]

def report(hires, today)
  hires = hires.select do |hire|
    # Do not use "!" after select
    # Unless you want to keep the variable value after method's run
    day_interval = (today - hire[:date]).to_i # The default return is Rational

    VACATION_INTERVAL.include?(day_interval)
  end

  hires.each { |hire| puts(format('%s, needs vacation', hire[:name])) }
end

today = Date.today
```

As it depends on your code context, I just added the 'select' lines, and removed the lines that your 'format' method wasn't using

---

I changed your "hires" variable to match 91 to 97 days of interval from today to give you the following example (because for today, August 17th, none matched from your example);

```ruby
hires = [
  { name: 'Jerry', date: Date.new(2021, 8, 15) },
  { name: 'Berry', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 14) },
  { name: 'Jack', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 16) }
]
```

and executing

```rb
report(hires,today)
```

Outputs;

```rb
Berry, needs vacation
Jack, needs vacation
```

But the method is still returning the array, so be careful with that

Answer (score 0):

You can write that as follows.

```
require 'date'

def need_vacation(hires, reference_date, days_ago_range)
  target_date_range = reference_date - days_ago_range.last..
    reference_date-days_ago_range.first
  hires.each { |hire| puts "#{hire[:name]} needs a vacation" if
    target_date_range.cover?(hire[:date]) }
end
```

Let's try it.

```
hires = [
  { name: 'Jerry', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 12) },
  { name: 'Berry', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 21) },
  { name: 'Jack', date: Date.new(2021, 5, 17) }
]
days_ago_range = 91..97
reference_date = Date.new(2021, 8, 17)
  #=> #<Date: 2021-08-17 ((2459444j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

```
need_vacation(reference_date, days_ago_range)
Jerry needs a vacation
Jack needs a vacation
```

In the example, `target_date_range` is found to be `2021-05-12..2021-05-18`, a range of `Date` objects.  Computing this range once is preferable to making date calculations for each element of `hires`, especially when `hires` is large.

I set `reference_date` to today's date, rather than to `Date.today` so that my example will endure beyond midnight tonight.

See [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F).